# Smarty doesn't display multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, smarty, multidimensional-array

I have problem with displaying my array in smarty. It looks like this. Declaration of array:

index.php:

```
$rewrites = array(
'en' => array(
'homepage' => 'homepage'
),

'de' => array(
'homepage' => 'zuhause'
),
);

$smarty->assign('rewrites', $rewrites);
```

And in template file:

```
{$rewrites|@print_r}
{$rewrites[de][homepage]}
```

First line prints whole array like it is, so array is assigned. But second line shows nothing, why? How to do it properly? If I do it like this {$rewrites.de.homepage} it works but I really need to declare my array value like this {$rewrites[de][homepage]} because 'de' comes from other variable, that define current language. My target is {$rewrites[$lang][homepage]} for example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648042/smarty-how-to-reference-to-the-associative-array-index

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
{$rewrites[$lang]['homepage']}
```

You can use also:

```
{$rewrites.{$lang}.homepage}
```

Comment: See the update of my response

Comment: Well, when I'm trying like you wrote, I have an error of smarty.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this:

```
{$rewrites.de.homepage}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do is as follows `{$rewrites[$lang].homepage}`